# AC23678 - What does it mean on an LED light bulb?

Tags: led, light-bulb

I'm trying to replace all the 36deg beam angle LED light bulbs in my home with bulbs with a much greater beam angle. While trying to shop for the right bulbs, I came across the spec "AV23678" printed on the existing bulbs. I have not been able to figure out what this means. Can anyone help? What does this mean and how critical is it to match this spec while shopping for new lights?

if it helps, the current LED light bulbs are from OSRAM.

The full specs are - MR16 50 VAL HV 5.5W 865 36deg GU5.3 230V AC23678 50/60HZ 525lm 45mA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost certainly not a specification but a part number, or possibly a batch number.

Ignore it, at least if you're not trying to get a match between bulbs.  If you want to replace one of a set, and not have it look different to the others, trying to get the same part number ought to help - but manufacturers of commodity items can and do sell the same part number with different components

Because it's not really there for consumers, it's not likely to be listed shopping online.  It may not even be printed on the box if you find them in a real shop.

What you do want to match is the fitting and voltage.  **MR16** seems to be the same as **GU5.3**, but these fittings are also used at lower voltages, so also match the **230V**.  The number of lumens should be *broadly similar* if you're happy with the overall amount of light your existing ones give, but as you're looking for more spread out light, you might want to round up rather than down.

Comment: It doesn't matter to us, but at a guess, AC23 might encode the fact it's a 230VAC part, the 678th 230VAC part from the division of OSRAM that uses part numbers of that format, which is probably all retail lighting products.  I know OSRAM use a very different format for the part numbers of individual LEDs, encoding more information